# autoformater and symbols like ñ

Tags: formatting, aptana, aptana3

In Aptana ( Eclipse 3.7.2 with Aptana Studio plugin 3.1.3 ) when i activate the autoformater ( ctrt + shift + f ) and a css file contains a letter `ñ` , the formatter puts a newline, how change this behavior ?

In the line with the symbol, aptana marks `Syntax error: unexpected token ñ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scape character for add other characters like `ñ`  with `\ñ` for example.